# Add three dots at end of nth line

Tags: jquery, css

We are getting content from backend , and we need to show only three lines . At the end of third line we need to add three dots .

What i have done till now to get three lines -

```
var height = $(this).find('.sample').outerHeight();
var lineHeight = $(this).find('p').css('line-height');
$(this).find('.sample').css('max-height',lineHeight*3);

.sample{overflow: hidden;}
```

Here three lines are getting displayed . But how to add dots ? I have tried webkits but it do not work on ie .

Comment: css after selector or via jquery append('....')

Comment: "*I have tried webkits*" - what specific 'webkits' have you tried? Please show your "*[mcve]*" code in order that we can reproduce your problem, and provide specific practicable help, both for you and for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  .add-three-dots{display: inline-block;

   width: 240px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   background: #FFFCD7;
    padding: 5px;
     }
```

```
      <span class="add-three-dots">How To Add Three Dots In the End Of String with Css And Jquery?</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

maybe this code do not work in IE browser